# passing key/value pairs from javascript to C# code behind

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, serialization

if I want to pass key/value pairs from javascript to C# ASP.NET code behind, should I use querystring parameters, hidden value or other methods? Values are not from the form, so jquery serialize or params() won't work..I guess I have to serialize it manually?? Values come from dropdownlist (name/selected option text) pairs

Comment: What kind of C# code (ASP.NET? MVC?) -- and where do the values come from?

Answer (score 2):

That's what JSON is for. Most Javascript frameworks have JSON serializer built-in. Probably C# has a JSON module as well (but I don't know). You could also use XHR to send it.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest, most universally compatible way to do this is by appending the key-value-collection to the querystring.  It will be available in ASP.NET from  `HttpContext.Request.QueryString`.

That being said, there are a variety of ways to accomplish your goal.  You could send an `$.ajax` request using the serialized values.  If you want to get the serialized values in jQuery by serializing the form, you can add elements to the form prior to serializing.

Comment: can you show me a quick example how to append querystring values in js?

Comment: @stewiegriffin, Check out [jsuri](http://code.google.com/p/jsuri/).  It is a fluent JavaScript library for parsing and manipulating Uri strings.  It is pretty powerful, and the particular method to do what you want is `addQueryParam(key, value[,index])`.  The source of the string manipulation can be found at http://code.google.com/p/jsuri/source/browse/jsuri.js#328 .

Answer (score 0):

probably best to pass it as JSON and then use a JSON library (or WCF) to convert it

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by having a hidden server tag and include an onclientclick attribute on your postback button(s).

```
<input id="hdnKV" runat="server" />
<asp:Button id="btnSubmit" runat="server" onclientclick="selectKeyValues();" onclick="btnSubmit_OnClick">Submit</asp:Button>
```

This onclientclick javascript function would populate this hidden value from your key value pairs.

```
function selectKeyValues() {

    var kv= getKeyValues(),
        hiddenValue = document.getElementById('<%= hdnKV.ClientID =>');

    hiddenValue.Value = kv;

}
```

It's not stated what data you have but you can probably use the following format for keyvalue pairs.

```
key1=value1,key2=value2,key3=value3
```

Comment: this is easy way to send it over C# code, but ugly to deserialize it in the code behind

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I solve it by something like this :

I prepare my array inside of a **foreach** loop in **JavaScript**

```
var itemIdVersionCollection = [];
var itemName = row[1];
var version  = row[2];
var key = { Key: itemId , Value: version };
itemIdVersionCollection.push(key);
```

My **Model** was something like this :

```
public class IdVersion
{
    public int? Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class SomeModel 
{
   public List<IdVersion> ItemIdVersion { get; set; } 
}
```

The **action** :

```
Public ActionResult MethodName(SomeModel model)
```